# Dictionary comprehension with lambda expression fails to produce desired result

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, closures, dictionary-comprehension

I'm creating a one liner to map the string of int to a function testing if the values are matched. Ideally, the result dictionary `d` behaves like `d['0'](0) is True` and `d['0'](1) is False`. But instead, I get the following output:

```
>>> d = { str(i): lambda v: v == i for i in range(3) }
>>> d['0'](0)
False
>>> d['0'](2)
True
```

I'm guessing the reason being lazy evaluation. I guess I could build the dictionary with a `for` loop correctly but I want a one line expression instead.

Can anyone explain why this approach fails and how I do it right?

Comment: Also have a look at: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: Not really anything to do with lazy evaluation, just how function namespaces work in Python.

Comment: The correct term is _late binding_. Certainly, a good answer would address that.

Comment: "I guess I could build the dictionary with a for loop correctly but I want a one line expression instead." It would work the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the current value of `i` for each lambda which can be done via the default argument `i=i`. See:

```
>>> d = { str(i): lambda v, i=i: v == i for i in range(3) }
>>> d['0'](0)
True
>>> d['0'](2)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative method to see things more logically.
    `d=dict((str(i),lambda v, i=i: v==i ) for i in range(3))`

this will give the same results as above